# The solution of equation $4+6+8+10+\cdots +x =270$ is 15.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The solution of equation 
$4+6+8+10+\cdots +x =270$ 
is $x=15$. 
How can I prove it? 
I ve tried the geometric sequence but I cannot figure out the pattern.

Comment: It is an arithmetic sequence since the terms have a common difference.

Comment: But then how can $x$ be $15$ ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. For the answer to be 15 then the question should have been something like: "How many terms in the sequence $4+6+8+10+\cdots+$to $n$ terms add to give a total of $270$?"

Comment: @GeorgiaS Where are you getting your questions from? Both questions you have posted today have been poorly written. The other question could not have been a transcription error so I suspect you are working from a low quality set of problems.

Comment: I am so sorry! They are taken from an old paper of Maths exams for a School of Medicine. They are multiple choice questions and I ve been trying to solve them for 1 week. It seems that they both have mistakes. Thank you for you time and I am really sorry for bothering you.

Comment: We are happy to help. If you are after practice questions in a particular area just post a question as there are many users here who could answer that one.

Answer (score 4):

Dividing both sides by 2 gives you:
$$2 + 3 + 4 + 5 ... + x/2 = 135$$

Adding 1 to both side of the equation then gives you:
$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 ... + x/2 =136$$

Since the sum of all integers from 1 to $n$ is defined as:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

We can rewrite the equation as:
$$\frac{x(x+2)}{8}= 136$$
$$x^2 + 2x - 1088 = 0$$
$$(x+34)(x-32)=0$$

Since $x$ must be positive:
$$x = 32$$

Comment: I fixed your answer because you factored the quadratic incorrectly. The real answer is $x=32$ since $4+6+8+10+12+14+16+18+20+22+24+26+28+30+32=270$. Note that this sum has $15$ terms.

Comment: Yes it was a factorizing mistake I thought my quadratic was $x^2 - 2x - 1088$. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is incorrect. In order for the question to make sense, we need to assume that $x=2n, n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \geq 4$.
In that case what you have is a sum of an arithmetic series.
The equation you get is
$$270 = \frac{x+4}{2}(1+\frac{x-4}{2})$$

This is a quadratic equation, solving it yields two solutions $x=32$ and $x=-34$ but of course you are only interested in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

$$4+6+8+10+\cdots +x=270\\ \frac { 4+x }{ 2 } \left( \frac { x-4 }{ 2 } +1 \right) =270\\ \frac { \left( 4+x \right)  }{ 2 } \frac { \left( x-2 \right)  }{ 2 } =270\\ \left( x-2 \right) \left( x+4 \right) =1080\\ { x }^{ 2 }+2x-1088=0\\ x=-1\pm \sqrt { 1089 } \\ x=32$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $$1+2+3+4+.....+(n-1)+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

$$2+4+6+8+.....+2(n-1)+2n = n(n+1)$$

That is $$4+6+8+.....+2(n-1)+2n = n(n+1)-2$$

Thus $$n(n+1)-2 \leq 270$$

$$n^2+n-272 \leq 0$$

$$(n+17)(n-16) \leq 0$$

So $$n=16$$

Thus $$4+6+8+10+12+14+16+18+20+22+24+26+28+30+32=270$$

I think the question should be $$(4+6+8+...)\cdot x =270$$

Then we can argue that factors of $270$ are $1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15,18,27,30,45,54,90,135,270$

Then the only chances are 
$$4+6 =10 $$ which gives $x=27$

$$4+6+8 = 18$$ which gives $x=15$

$$4+6+8+10+12+14 =54 $$ which gives $x=5$

$$4+6+8+10+12+14+16+18+20+22+24+26+28+30+32 = 270 $$ which gives $x=1$

Answer (score 0):

$x=15$ is not a solution to this equation. The question does NOT ask how many terms are in the series although it is the answer to that question that is given.

Furthermore, there is nothing in the question stating that $x$ is a term of the arithmetic series. If $x$ is a term of the series then it must be the 15th term. But as stated $x$ could be 0 since

\begin{equation}
4+6+8+10+ \cdots + 30 + 32 + 0=270
\end{equation}

But $x=32$ is also a solution since

\begin{equation}
4+6+8+10+ \cdots + 30 + 32 =270
\end{equation}

and $x=62$ is a solution since

\begin{equation}
4+6+8+10+ \cdots + 28 + 62 =270
\end{equation}

etc.

The solution set for $x$ is $\{270-n(n+3) \,\vert\, 4\le n\le 15\}$.